# Dependent random choice and sparse graphs

Tags: co.combinatorics

If we would like to embed a sparse graph into a dense graph, sometimes we can use the dependent random choice method. Now I would like to embed a graph into a sparse graph $G$, say $|E(G)|=o(n^{3/2})$. It is possible that any pair of distinct vertices have at most one common neighbor in $G$, so the classical dependent random choice method cannot be applied. Can we do something to adapt this technique to sparse graphs?

Comment: I am not aware of such techniques. it is open to prove that $ex(n,H)=o(n^{3/2})$ for general 2-degenerate bipartite graphs  graphs $H$ without a $C_4$. meanwhile, it was only discovered a few years ago that there exist $H$ which are not 2-degenerate and have $ex(n,H) =o(n^{3/2})$. regardless, I feel pretty confident that you would need to rely heavily on specific structure of your $H$ to get such a bound without significant new ideas.